# Como coletar e inserir propriedades de gradient de uma div para outra div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Existe este [site](http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator#'-moz-linear-gradient%5C%28left%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28248%5C%2C80%5C%2C50%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%200%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28241%5C%2C111%5C%2C92%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2050%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28246%5C%2C41%5C%2C12%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2051%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28240%5C%2C47%5C%2C23%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2071%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28231%5C%2C56%5C%2C39%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%20100%5C%25%5C%29%5C%3B') gerador de gradiente CSS.

E lá, como podem ver, quando clicamos nos pequenos quadradinhos de escolha com gradient ele carrega todas as propriedades gradient para outra div maior.

Pesquisei aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp

**html_toggleclass.asp**

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    console.log($("div").css("background"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="width:100px;height:100px;background: rgba(248,80,50,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(248,80,50,1) 0%, rgba(241,111,92,1) 50%, rgba(246,41,12,1) 51%, rgba(240,47,23,1) 71%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(248,80,50,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(241,111,92,1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(246,41,12,1)), color-stop(71%, rgba(240,47,23,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(231,56,39,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(248,80,50,1) 0%, rgba(241,111,92,1) 50%, rgba(246,41,12,1) 51%, rgba(240,47,23,1) 71%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(248,80,50,1) 0%, rgba(241,111,92,1) 50%, rgba(246,41,12,1) 51%, rgba(240,47,23,1) 71%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(248,80,50,1) 0%, rgba(241,111,92,1) 50%, rgba(246,41,12,1) 51%, rgba(240,47,23,1) 71%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(248,80,50,1) 0%, rgba(241,111,92,1) 50%, rgba(246,41,12,1) 51%, rgba(240,47,23,1) 71%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f85032', endColorstr='#e73827', GradientType=0 );"></div>
    
<button>Botão</button>
```

Mas não está mostrando as propriedades gradient no console.
Como o site faz pra inserir um gradient de uma div para outra div coletando e inserindo?

Comment: Recomendo que você use uma classe pra tanto css, considere que você ja esta fazendo errado por conta disso. Acho que `element.computedStyle `ou `element.style` é o mais proximo que você consegue na situação atual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O porquê de o jQuery não estar buscando corretamente a informação, não sei dizer. Dei uma pesquisada rápida e não encontrei um material adequado. Parece que ele não considera o *inline style* do elemento como parte do CSS e, por isso, sempre retorna vazio.

Mas, uma forma prática de se contornar isso é acessar diretamente a propriedade `style` e buscar o atributo `background` do mesmo, como abaixo:

```
$("div").prop('style').background
```

Ficando:

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    console.log($("div").prop('style').background);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="width:100px;height:100px;background: rgba(248,80,50,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(248,80,50,1) 0%, rgba(241,111,92,1) 50%, rgba(246,41,12,1) 51%, rgba(240,47,23,1) 71%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(248,80,50,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(241,111,92,1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(246,41,12,1)), color-stop(71%, rgba(240,47,23,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(231,56,39,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(248,80,50,1) 0%, rgba(241,111,92,1) 50%, rgba(246,41,12,1) 51%, rgba(240,47,23,1) 71%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(248,80,50,1) 0%, rgba(241,111,92,1) 50%, rgba(246,41,12,1) 51%, rgba(240,47,23,1) 71%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(248,80,50,1) 0%, rgba(241,111,92,1) 50%, rgba(246,41,12,1) 51%, rgba(240,47,23,1) 71%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(248,80,50,1) 0%, rgba(241,111,92,1) 50%, rgba(246,41,12,1) 51%, rgba(240,47,23,1) 71%, rgba(231,56,39,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f85032', endColorstr='#e73827', GradientType=0 );"></div>
    
<button>Botão</button>
```

Perceba que, ao pressionar o botão, é devidamente exibido a configuração do gradiente no console.